# One-to-One cascading persisting throws 'NULL not allowed for the foreign-key column' JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Suppose I have two entites **A** and **B**.

A owns B and when A is created, B must also be created.
When A is deleted, the associated B should also be deleted.
(Hence I put cascade in the class A rather than B)
But for some reasons I put the foreign key **aId** in the table **B**.

It should look like:

[image]

**B owns the foreign key column, but to my domain A should be the owner.**

Here's my tentative code

```java
@Entity
public class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;
    ...
}


@Entity
public class B{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
    private A a;
}
```

Turns out:

When I save A through the Spring JPA repository, it throws something like

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
NULL not allowed for column "AID"; SQL statement:
insert into B(id, aId, ...) values (null, ?, ...)
```

It seems not first **save the instance A with its id generated then save B** assoticated to the created A, turns out breaking the not-null constraints on aid.

How to properly solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Entity
public class A{
    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;
    ...
}


@Entity
public class B{
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
    private A a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private B b;

    public void setB(String b) {
       this.b = b;
       if (b != null) 
         b.setA(this);
    }  
}


@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
    private A a;
}
```